# Two questions about commutative theories

Tags: universal-algebra, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a commutative algebraic theory (for example sets, abelian groups, commutative monoids, but not groups etc.). References include the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory) and Borceux' *Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2*, section 3.10. Then $\mathsf{Mod}(\mathcal{T})$ is a monoidal category with internal homs.

**Question 1.** (**Answered:** Yes) Can we find a property of concrete categories which holds for $\mathsf{Mod}(\mathcal{T})$ if and only if $\mathcal{T}$ is commutative? In other words, does commutativity of an algebraic category not depend on the presentation?

**Question 2.** (**Answered:** No) Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a commutative algebraic theory and $C=\mathsf{Mod}(\mathcal{T})$. Assume that $X \in C$ is a Co-$C$-algebra, i.e. we have a factorization of $\hom(X,-) : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ over $C$. Does this have to coincide with the usual factorization? This is well-known to be true in the examples I have mentioned above, for example for every abelian group $A$ there is only one natural abelian group structure on the hom-sets $\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$. 
This should be all well-known, but I don't know a reference.

Comment: To me a "presentation" of an algebraic theory is a choice of operations and axioms, while Lawvere theories and monads embody the extensional essence of an algebraic theory. In any case, I think the answer to question 1 is negative: being a commutative algebraic theory is not stable under Morita equivalence, since e.g. the theory of $k$-modules for a field $k$ is commutative, but the theory of $\textrm{Mat}_n(k)$-modules is not for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Yes but these categories are not equivalent *as concrete categories*.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I said _Morita_ equivalence. Once you have fixed a forgetful functor, then the category entirely determines the algebraic theory. (To construct the symmetric monoidal closed structure you only need to know that the monad admits a commutative structure.)

Comment: Why can't we consider the commutativity condition on the monad $Ran_U U$ as a condition on the concrete category $U: Mod(T) \to Set$? 

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1392/why-all-these-answers-as-comments/

Comment: Um, Martin, as a courtesy I was trying to clarify whether you were expecting something else as regards question 1, since the comment seems to be something of a simple observation. Also, I wanted to think more about your question 2. But, I'm happy to put down my comment as an answer, as long as *you're* happy. (Later, since I have to dash off to do something.) 


Comment: s this, ncatlab.org/nlab/show/… , an answer to question 1? I guess that depends on what the Kronecker product is.

Comment: FOr fixing ideas let  $\mathcal{T}$= "commutive monoids", let $x\in C$.
A factorization of $\hom(x,-) : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ over $C$ is  a CM-structre (read commutative monoid structure) on $hom(x, y)$ natural in $y\in C$, this is equivalent  (Yoneda) to a CM-structure  on  $x\in C^{op}$.   
Because $C$ is closed, every $x\in C$ as a natural  op-CM-structure. THe question become to find two different commutative comonoid structure (i.e. op-CM-structure) on some commutative monoid $x$ (I guess there are but I dont know very well  monoid theory).

Comment: @Buschi Sergio: Bimodules, see the other comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for question 1: commutativity doesn't depend on the presentation of $T$. If $M = Mod(T)$ and $U: M \to Set$ is the forgetful functor, then commutativity can be formulated as saying that the monad $Ran_U U = U \circ Ran_U 1_M$ is commutative (or monoidal) in the sense of the nLab article [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+monad). Perhaps the most interesting aspect of this is that commutativity is a *property*, not an extra structure on a monad (where the structure of a strength constraint on an endofunctor on $Set$ is canonically given because every such endofunctor is canonically $Set$-enriched). These observations also lift to the enriched setting, provided of course that the functors involved are given as enriched functors (with respect to a base of enrichment $V$).

(Note: $Ran_U 1_M$, which invariably exists, is just the left adjoint $F$ of $U$ if $U$ has a left adjoint. Some related discussion on the codensity monad of a general functor $U: M \to Set$ can be found in [this post](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/09/where_do_monads_come_from.html) by Tom Leinster.)

**Edit:** I had responded to question 2 earlier, but I am now editing that response out as it is superseded by Martin's second comment below, which makes the situation quite clear. Apologies for the noise.

Comment: Hm, I think that 2) is wrong: Note that 2) is equivalent to the assertion that the enriched Yoneda embedding $C^{op} \to \hom_c(C,C)$ is an equivalence (here $c$ stands for continuous functors). Now take $C=$left $k$-modules for some ring $k$. Then it is well-known (special case of Eilenberg-Watts) that the right hand side equals the category of $k$-bimodules. Even when $k$ is commutative, this is not just $k$-modules.

Comment: Martin, you're absolutely right, and that's a very clear way to look at the situation. I'm now going to edit my answer, and delete some comments which are now obsolete. 